# C++ error message

Tags: c++, linked-list, polynomials

I'm getting the error message segmentation fault for the following function. I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this problem

```
Polynomial Polynomial :: multiply(const Polynomial& p) const{
  //The functions returns the mathematical product of the host polynomial and p

  // new object created
  Polynomial multiply;
  // node that points to the beginning of the list
  Node *temporary = m_head;

  Node *copy = p.m_head;

  long num_coeff;

  unsigned int num_deg;

  while(temporary -> m_next != NULL){
    copy = p.m_head;
    while(copy -> m_next != NULL){
      Polynomial variable;
      num_coeff = temporary -> m_coefficient * copy -> m_coefficient;
      num_deg = temporary -> m_degree + copy -> m_degree;
      variable.insertMonomial(num_coeff, num_deg);
      multiply.add(variable);
      copy = copy -> m_next;
    }
    temporary = temporary -> m_next;
  }
  return multiply; 
}
```

Comment: where exactly is the segmentation fault occuring? Are you sure `m_head` is not null on entry to the function? how about `p.m_head`?

Comment: I'd just use a `std::vector` rather than a linked list. And if you feel that you absolutely must use a linked list, well there's `std::list` for you. Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you! I did initialize m_head to be null in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet that you are running into segmentation fault because you don't have the right tests in the conditionals of the `while` statements.

You are using `temporary -> m_next != NULL`. What happens when `temporary` is `NULL`?

Instead of

```
while(temporary -> m_next != NULL){
   copy = p.m_head;
   while(copy -> m_next != NULL){
```

you should use

```
while(temporary != NULL){
   copy = p.m_head;
   while(copy != NULL){
```